# What does it mean to multiply a duration by a duration?

Tags: go

To my surprise, this compiled

```
fmt.Println(time.Second * time.Second)
```

The result is nonsense

```
277777h46m40s
```

It doesn't make any sense to multiply a duration by duration and get another duration.

What's going on?

Comment: In Physics, it does make sense. For example the dimension of acceleration is [m/s^2], wherein time is squared. E.g. 9.81m/s^2 for the earth's gravitational acceleration.

Comment: The question is valid and the problem of the OP is clear. The answer will help him understanding the programming language that he uses. This question should not be downvoted without further explanation.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The [Duration type](http://golang.org/pkg/time/#Duration) is simply an int64 representing the duration as a  nanosecond count

> type Duration int64
>
> A Duration represents the elapsed time between two instants as an int64 nanosecond count.

So multiplying one duration by another gives the result of multiplying the number of nanoseconds in each. In my example, this gives a billion billion nanoseconds, or `277777h46m40s`. Nonsense, but well-defined!

Comment: To expand on that a bit, the language defines `Duration` as an integer type that's convenient for calculating real-world durations, but it doesn't enforce meaningful operations. It's entirely up to you, the programmer, to do only things that make sense. (And conceivably, you could multiply two `Duration`s, then divide the result by another `Duration` and get a sensible result.) There are software packages that do more elaborate unit computations, where dividing distance by time reliably gives you a speed, but `Duration` is not part of such a package.

Comment: There is nothing particularly nonsense about time squared. It's just unfamiliar. It appears in plenty of mechanics equations, such as s = u t + 0.5 a t^2

Comment: @Rick-777 I agree '2 seconds times 2 seconds equals 4 square seconds' is reasonable, but Go gives 4 billion seconds!

Comment: @ColonelPanic: It gives you a number that can reasonably be interpreted as 4e18 square nanoseconds, which *is* 4 square seconds. The stringification of a Nanoseconds quantity assumes a linear quantity -- but you, as a programmer, don't have to.

Comment: @KeithThompson I hadn't thought of it like that.